# Probability of putting black and white balls in the same box

Tags: probability

Given:

**N** black balls

> b1, b2, b3, ..., bn

**N** white balls

> w1, w2, w3, ..., wn

**N** boxes

A random guys comes in, and puts 2 balls in each box, what is the probability of putting a white ball and a black ball in each box?

---

My effort:

Find all the possible ways to divide the 2N balls into group of 2.

[image]

Then find all the possible combinations for a black and a white ball, which is the Cartesian product. `N^2`

Then answer is:
[image]

But it seems I am wrong?

The original problem is a bit different, **N** guests take off their shoes, and some random guy scrambles them into new pairs, what is the probability of putting them in pairs where a left shoe is assigned to a right shoe.

Perhaps trying to think about this problem in a black-white problem was not a smart decision?

Any help is appreciated as it seems I have a mistake?

Comment: What does the formula $\dfrac{n\choose 2}{2!}$ mean for you? I don't think it really does what you describe.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier you are right. I meant to count the number of ways to make pairs out of 2N balls. It should have been 2N choose 2 I believe.

Comment: 2N choose 2 is the number of ways to make *one* pair out of 2N. Then you still have N-1 pairs to go if you go this way.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier you are right. I can consider each 2 indexes (i,i+1) as a pair. Then I have `(2n)!` different ways of making couple of the 2 balls.

Comment: Yes :) I made an answer but you are on the right track!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is really dangerous to apply raw formulas in probability, that is what leaves the most room for mistakes. The best is imho to recall what the formulas do and somehow to reprove them every time.

So you have $2n\times (2n-1)$ options for the two balls to go in the first box, which has to be divided by $2$ if the order inside the box doesn't matter (thanks @2chromatic). Then $(2n-2)(2n-3)$ for the second box (again divided by 2), etc.

Therefore the total number of ways to put the balls in the boxes is $\dfrac{(2n)!}{2^n}$.

Now if you are to put only black/white couples, then you have $n\times n$ options for Box 1, $(n-1)\times (n-1)$ options for Box 2, etc. A total of $n!\times n!$ options.

The probability is therefore $$\dfrac{2^n(n!)^2}{(2n)!}$$
which happens to be equal to $$\dfrac{2^n }{{2n\choose n}}$$

Comment: When counting total number of ways, does the order matter inside the box? I took as if it does not and it brings a factor of $1/2^n$.

Comment: In that case it does, you are right. It also makes more sense, I will edit.

Comment: I noticed something, 2nx(2n-1) is wrong? as it has to be one white and one black? correct me if im wrong, should it not be nxn ?

Comment: That is the second part when you have this restriction. First you compute the total number of ways to do this without restriction.

Comment: Sorry you are right :)